# Spring boot - Database changes does not reflect until job completes

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing a batch job using Spring Boot and Maven using java 1.8. Database is Sybase ASE
When I try to debug my code, all the database statements(insert, update etc) seems to run but I could not find the data persist in the database until the job is completed.
Why isn't the records available in database as soon as the query is finished?
Also if the job has failed/Exception occured, the whole database transactions are not stored in the database.

Could anyone explain how Spring database transactions work?

Comment: did you add @transactional annotation on your function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityManager flushes the changes after the transaction has been completed. Before you cannot view the changes in your database.

If a @Transaction Annotation is present on the method remove this. But be aware that you do not have a transaction anymore. Alternative you could use EntityManager.flush().